# What can I use to create the impression of an arch over my garage door?

Tags: doors, garage

What can I use to create the impression of an arch over my garage door?

Comment: You would reduce the overhead clearance at the sides.  Is that what you want?  Or you could build up something that looks similar to the door panels (depending on your door construction) and attach it to the wall above the door.

Comment: Could you post an example and a photo of your current garage

Comment: It's an interesting question, but a vague one. You'd typically _make_ something like that, as variation in style and implementation would make it unsuited to mass production. I suggest revising to ask something more specific about _your_ situation. I consider the question off topic as it is. We're not a discussion forum. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

"false facade?"   We'll let that pass.   A simple approach would be to cut a curve on one side of a trim board.  You could make the arch as curved as you want:

[image]

Comment: The phrase isn't actually redundant, if that's what you were implying. It translates to "false _face_". A facade isn't necessarily false.

Comment: Not redundant, a double negative.  A false facade of brick...would be real brick....no?

Comment: fascade actually has [two meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/facade) and Steve & @isherwood have each picked different ones. One is simply "the front of a building", the other implies a "false face". I'd agree that "false fascade" does feel quite redundant, but in many ways, it's simply being  more precise.